# failed building wheel for pocketsphinx

Tags: python, macos, swig, pocketsphinx

(`Macosx`) I've been trying to install `textract` using `pip install textract`, but I get the below error message. I've installed `pocketsphinx` and `swig` already. I also don't know what the message about `requests 2.18.4 has requirement chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2, but you'll have chardet 2.3.0 which is incompatabile`

I'd really appreciate if someone could walk me through what this means and how I can move on to install `textract`. relatively new to python so the simpler the language the better.

Here's what I thought to be the relevant error message:

```
Failed building wheel for pocketsphinx
  Running setup.py clean for pocketsphinx
Failed to build pocketsphinx
requests 2.18.4 has requirement chardet<3.1.0,>=3.0.2, but you'll have chardet 2.3.0 which is incompatible.
Installing collected packages: pocketsphinx, textract
  Found existing installation: pocketsphinx 0.1.15
    Uninstalling pocketsphinx-0.1.15:
      Successfully uninstalled pocketsphinx-0.1.15
  Running setup.py install for pocketsphinx ... error
    Complete output from command /anaconda3/bin/python -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='/private/var/folders/d8/hyzy1y7s4sd46jxz4chrhfcc0000gn/T/pip-install-dn569xpj/pocketsphinx/setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record /private/var/folders/d8/hyzy1y7s4sd46jxz4chrhfcc0000gn/T/pip-record-j1sxbma0/install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile:
    running install
    running build_ext
    building 'sphinxbase._ad' extension
    swigging swig/sphinxbase/ad.i to swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c
    swig -python -modern -Ideps/sphinxbase/include -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/sphinxbase -I/System/Library/Frameworks/OpenAL.framework/Versions/A/Headers -Ideps/sphinxbase/include/android -Ideps/sphinxbase/swig -outdir sphinxbase -o swig/sphinxbase/ad_wrap.c swig/sphinxbase/ad.i
    dyld: Library not loaded: @rpath/libpcre.1.dylib
      Referenced from: /usr/local/bin/swig
      Reason: image not found
    error: command 'swig' terminated by signal 6
```

Comment: It says you have a problem with swig installation, you should report it to original authors then.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this issue because I tried to install swig manually from the developer site. Running "brew install swig glpk" instead fixed it for me.